# Changing the picture when calling a new activity

Tags: java, android

I want to set an image to `ImageView` as soon as I call a new activity. But for some reason, I can't do it, although seems to be alright

Here is an XML snippet

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/magneticImgBox"
            android:layout_width="327dp"
            android:layout_height="211dp"
            android:src="@drawable/magneticimg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/magneticNameBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/magneticImgBox"
            android:text="Набор Magnetic"
            android:textSize="35sp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxDiscrition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/magneticNameBox"
            android:text="Бюджетный комплект, который не имеет каких-то дополнительных функций, но до сих пор пользуется спросом и выполняет свои функции без проблем.
            \n\nВ комплекте:\n- Антенна\n- Гарнитура с микрофоном\n- Извлекатель-внедритель\n- Магнитные динамики - 2шт.\n- Батарейка Крона"/>

    <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/magneticVideoPlayerBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/boxDiscrition"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a Java snippet

```
public void openExamLight(View view) {
    MagneticActivity mag = new MagneticActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MagneticActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    mag.changePicture();
}
```

```
public void changePicture() {
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.magneticImgBox);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.magneticimg);
}
```

Here I showed the method of clicking in which I call a new activity (open Magnetic) and the method in which I try to change the picture (changePicture, yes, I know that it could not be taken out in a separate method, it's just an attempt to fix everything)

Comment: Why don't you use intent bundle for this? send a boolean value when you want to change and receive that value and call your function.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're talking about, I just started learning android development

Comment: Let me show you how you can achieve this. ````public void openExamLight(View view) {
    MagneticActivity mag = new MagneticActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MagneticActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}````
and in your MagneticActivity onCreate function 
````@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");
   if(yourBool) {
   changePicture();
}
}
````

Comment: this didn't help either, the app crashes,
in debug outputs this:
Process: com.example.microgadgets, PID: 10370
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.microgadgets/com.example.microgadgets.MagneticActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I had to do a type conversion in the changePicture method

```
public void changePicture() {
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.magneticImgBox);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.magneticimg);
}
```